# 'The RPC server is unavailable.' when looping through word documents

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I am working on a utility to find and update DOC VARIABLES in Word. I have a section of code to loop through the documents and present a Message Box with the variable name, but I'm receiving an error when it tries to open the next document. The error is:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

I'm confused because my code does not access any network. I think what might be happening is the Word is closing when the document closes, but I cannot find a solution to prevent that.

Other things I've tried:

1. Confirmed UAC is Disabled
2. Confirmed RPC Services are Running
3. Confirmed Registry Values for RPC and DCOM are correct

   ```
   Private Sub LoopTemp()
       Dim oDir As New DirectoryInfo(dPath)
       Dim oFileArr As FileInfo() = oDir.GetFiles()
       Dim oFile As FileInfo
       Dim oVar As Variable
       Dim oDoc = New Document()

       Dim oWord As Application
       oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
       oWord.Visible = False

       For Each oFile In oFileArr
          oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.FullName)

          For Each oVar In oDoc.Variables
              MsgBox(oVar.Name)
          Next

          oDoc.Close(SaveChanges:=WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges)

       Next
       oWord.Quit()
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Where do you run the code listed above? Is it from asp.net or service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RPC error appears when a "pointer" to a COM object is not correctly released from memory before code tries to re-use it. This is a common enough problem when automating Office applications from outside the application, itself. Especially when working from .NET great care must be used.

Another very important thing to note is that the `New` keyword should never be used with any Office object *except* `Application`. Although the APIs allow it, never use `New Document` with Word as this creates a `Document` object that can't be correctly released.

For reasons of efficiency, starting the Word application *once* should be sufficient - it's not necessary to repeat that within a loop, as long as the COM objects it uses are correctly released (set to `Nothing` and garbage collected).

I would write the code in the question as follows:

```
Private Sub LoopTemp()
    Dim oDir As New DirectoryInfo(dPath)
    Dim oFileArr As FileInfo() = oDir.GetFiles()
    Dim oFile As FileInfo
    Dim oVar As Variable = Nothing
    Dim oWord As Application = NOthing
    Dim oDoc As Document = Nothing

    oWord = New Word.Application
    oWord.Visible = False

    For Each oFile In oFileArr
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.FullName)
        For Each oVar In oDoc.Variables
            MsgBox(oVar.Name)
        Next
        oVar = Nothing
        oDoc.Close(SaveChanges:=WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges)
        oDoc = Nothing

        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
    Next

    oWord.Quit()
    oWord = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

End Sub
```

Comment: How can GC help if the `Application` goes away in the loop?

Comment: Where is the application going away in the loop *in my code*, @EugeneAstafiev? The only thing being released in the loop are the object created in the loop.

Comment: I believe that your code and poster's work correctly. But according to the error mentioned, the application becomes unavailable. How does the GC help to bridge the issue?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev The error occurs if *any* object is "left hanging" in memory, not just the application. GC will make sure those objects are *definitely* released before the loop tries to reassign them. In the VBA world, `Set object = Nothing` works "immediately" to relase the object; in the .NET world, the object first needs to be garbage collected, which is indeterminate unless GC if forced. It's a shame the excerpt from Andrew Whiteshapel's book is no longer posted in MS documentation - that explains the problem very well...

Comment: In .net world we deal with RCW objects, not real COM servers. If it is not set it doesn't mean we can re-use them later. So, I don't see any possible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Loop through .docx files replacing variables
Private Sub LoopTemp()
    Dim oDir As New DirectoryInfo(dPath)
    Dim oFileArr As FileInfo() = oDir.GetFiles()
    Dim oFile As FileInfo
    Dim oVar As Variable
    Dim oWord As Application

    For Each oFile In oFileArr

        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = False

        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

        Dim oDoc = New Document()
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.FullName)

        For Each oVar In oDoc.Variables
            MsgBox(oVar.Name)
        Next

        oDoc.Close(SaveChanges:=WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges)
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oDoc)

        oWord.Quit()
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWord)

    Next

End Sub
```

The updated code worked when I moved oWord into the loop. Now it creates a new object and quits for each document. I'm not sure if there's a better way.